# $\lim_{x\to{\infty}} (x-\sqrt{x^2+x})$

Tags: calculus, limits

Given this question $$\lim_{x\to{\infty}} (x-\sqrt{x^2+x})$$

Find the limit

Work so far...:

$$\lim_{x\to{\infty}} \frac{x^2-x^2-x}{x+\sqrt{x^2+x}}$$
 $$\lim_{x\to{\infty}} \frac{-x}{x+\sqrt{x^2+x}} $$

Would the easiest way to proceed to be dividing bottom and top by $x$?

If so then is this attempt correct?:

$$\lim_{x\to{\infty}}  \frac{-1}{1+\sqrt{x+\frac1x}}$$
 $$\lim_{x\to{\infty}}\frac{-1}{1+\sqrt\infty} $$

Something is wrong there..

Comment: One of the easiest ways.

Comment: When you divide by $x$ the denominator, you must carry $1/x^2$ inside the square root, so the denominator is $1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes $$\lim_{x\to{\infty}} \frac{-x}{x+\sqrt{x^2+x}} =\lim_{x\to{\infty}} \frac{-1}{1+\sqrt{1+1/x}} =\cdots$$

---

Alternatively set $1/x=h$ to get

$$\lim_{x\to{\infty}} (x-\sqrt{x^2+x})=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1+h}}h$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{1-(1+h)}h\cdot\dfrac1{\lim_{h\to0^+}(1+\sqrt{1+h})}=\cdots$$

Comment: how are you getting $\sqrt{1+\frac1x}$ on the denominator?

Comment: @Panthy, $x^2+x=x^2\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)$

Comment: Ah i see. Thank you for your help!